in power automate variable produced by JavaScript is visible as [object Object]
function ExecuteScript() {
  return (async function() {
      const CHECK_INTERVAL = 500; // Sprawdzenie co 500 ms
      const TIMEOUT        = 45000; // Maksymalny czas oczekiwania w milisekundach
      const startTime      = new Date().getTime(); // Czas rozpoczęcia

      while (new Date().getTime() - startTime < TIMEOUT) {
        // Pobierz element <div> o id="basicUdiDanger"
        const targetDiv = document.getElementById("basicUdiDanger");
        console.log("Result basicUdiDanger:", targetDiv);

        if (targetDiv) {
          console.log("targetDiv true");
          return "success"; // Zwróć "success" jako czysty tekst
        } else {
          console.log("targetDiv false");
        }

        // Czekaj przed następnym sprawdzeniem
        await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, CHECK_INTERVAL));
      }

      // Czas oczekiwania - zwróć "2ndstep"
      console.log("Nie znaleziono tekstu 'Wprowadź dane ręcznie' w <div> w ciągu 45 sekund.");
      return "2ndstep"; // Czas oczekiwania - zwróć "2ndstep"
    })()
    .then(result => {
      console.log("Script result:", result);
      return String(result); // Zwróć wynik jako czysty tekst
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.error("Error during execution:", error);
      return "error"; // Zwróć "error" jako czysty tekst w przypadku błędu
    });
}

in above code variable produced is not recognized by power automate. Is recognized as [object Object] I've tried to change it to string but doesn't help still not recognized by power automate,

ExecuteScript returns a promise.  Maybe whatever is calling ExecuteScript can't handle a promise (and displays Object object instead).
